# JavaScript: difference between this.whatever and prototype.whatever when inherits

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Having this code:

```
var Person = function(_name){
     this.name = _name;
}

Person.prototype.surname = 'Jiménez';
```

What's the difference between this.name and Person.prototype.surname, what changes when inherited? what's the difference then when:

```
var newPerson = new Person('Carlos');
```

Comment: Both are different properties. While the property "name" exists on the object newPerson, the property "surname" is inherited from the prototype.

Comment: Read some good book like "Javascript: The definitive guide" to learn Javascript.

Comment: Explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where the property is defined,
.name is defined on the actual newPerson object while .surname is defined on newPerson's  prototype object.
if you were to create 2 Person objects the two will share the same .surname property but each will have its own .name property.

notice that once you assign a different value to .surname on an object like this

`newPerson.surname = 'some name';`

you actually defines a completely new property on the object. the only way to go back to view the prototype value is to do

`delete newPerson.surname;`

Comment: so for the this.name there isn't a chain?

Comment: .name property does not exists in newPerson's prototype chain so it is not part of the chain.
this.name by itself is a string primitive so it doesn't have a prototype chain.

other than primitives and the base Object in javascript every object has a prototype chain (many of which just points to Object)